# URL Rewrite to Remove .php in my Nginx PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, centos7, fpm

I setup Nginx PHP-FPM, with Centos 7, and Virtualmin control panel. I want to have all pages a SEO Friendly link without .php.

System automatically create configuration : `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

And empty folder: `etc/nginx/conf.d/`

nginx.conf :

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;


        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
          include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

           location / {
           }

        #error_page 404 /404.html;
           location = /40x.html{
       }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }         
    }




# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    server {
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        listen My.Domain.IP.Address;
        root /home/mydomain/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;        
        access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log;
        error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log;       
        fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomain/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mydomain/public_html;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
        }
        listen My.Domain.IP.Address:443 default ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/mydomain/ssl.combined;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomain/ssl.key;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 30;


    }


}
```

I found many information include the code below makes url working without .php
But after applying that, the page just shown 404 not found page.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

My question is, where should I insert the code above? what is completed code so it will work. May be I miss some parameter. If I must create a .conf file in `etc/nginx/conf.d/` what is the complete code that i must put in the conf file?

Any help is much appreciated. (please note that `My.Domain.IP.Address` is replace with an IP address, and mydomain is a website domain name.).

Comment: Presumably the configuration in your question is working correctly albeit with a `.php` extension. It would be helpful to see the access log and error log entries which genertate the 404 response and the configuration **after** you make the changes.

Comment: Richard Smith , Yes working with .php. 
But when doing configuration and testing with url rewrite, there is no any error log with 404. 
Only this error come up : **"conflicting server name "www.mydomain.com" on My.Domain.IP.Address:80, ignored"** 
Just did last test, it seem start to work. By placing the seo freindly code just above : listen My.Domain.IP.Address:443 default ssl; Just several line from bottom of nginx.conf 
But conflicting server name error still exist. What is the solution?

Comment: Just add a correction. I added the code just under "fastcgi_read_timeout 30;". is working too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, where should I insert the code above?

The `server` block for your domain contains one `location` block. The other two `location` blocks need to be added to that same `server` block.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html;

    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }    
    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^ $1.php last;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
    }

    ...
}
```

> But conflicting server name error still exist. What is the solution?

Use `nginx -T` (that's an uppercase `T`) to test the Nginx configuration file **and** view the entire configuration across all the included files. Inspect the `server_name` directives and identify where the duplicated name is coming from.

Just because your distribution includes `include` directives and directories to help organise your configuration across multiple files, you do not need to use them. Keeping the entire configuration in a single `nginx.conf` can be convenient for simpler servers.

Comment: Thank you. For seo friendly without .php already working, but l just confused with any code that are placed under : listen 80 default_server; server block, not working at all. In this case i place https redirect not working : return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

Answer (score 0):

Hello make the following modifications

remove from your code:

```
@extensionless-php;

 location @extensionless-php {
       rewrite ^ $1.php last;
   }

.php$ {
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, could you write a complete code?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /home/mydomain/public_html;

...
location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
            # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't 
break when using query string
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you, will keep this for reference.